# Python substitutes one of the parameters into self

Tags: python, function, self, python-3.2

I have encountered a funny situation in Python that I cannot resolve. I have a function
definition inside one class like 

`def a(self, x, y):` and it's been called from other place like `a(par1, par2)`. However, what happens is that `par1` gets substituted instead of `self`, `par2` instead of `x` and `y` is left uninitialized. But that shouldn't be the case: `par1` and `par2` should have been placed instead of `x` and `y` respectively and Python should have got `self` himself. This works correctly in Python 2.7, however this funny thing happens in 3.2 . The method a doesn't have any modifiers, however the method where I am calling it from has `@classmethod` modifier. It's a bit weird, maybe @classmethod was changed in the third version. If anybody knows what is going on or how to make things work correctly, please tell.

Thank you !

Comment: Should you be calling `a` like `<instance>.a(par1, par2)`?

Comment: can you show a full example of what your code looks like?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, runnable example of the behavior?

Comment: This calls out for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that works in Python 2.7 and fails in Python 3.2

Comment: How are you calling the `a` method? `a(par1, par2)` on its own will never work. You can't be doing `self.a(par1, par2)`, since you said you're in a `classmethod` so you don't have a `self` parameter. `cls.a(par1, par2)` will give you the error you've mentioned in Python3, but would fail with the error given in Ethan's answer in Python2. If you're calling it on a completely different object like `foo.a(par1, par2)` then it shouldn't be relevant that you're calling it from a classmethod.

Comment: it is useful to include relevant code in your questions...

Answer (score 0):

From your description I'm guessing code similar to this:

```
class Test(object):

    def a(self, par1, par2='empty'):
        print(self, par1, par2)

    @classmethod
    def b(cls, fjord):
        print(fjord)
        cls.a('par1', 'par2')

test = Test()
test.a('this', 'that')
test.b('cold')
```

In 2.7 this crashes like so:

```
(<__main__.Test object at 0x00B4A710>, 'this', 'that')

cold

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    test.b('cold')
  File "test.py", line 7, in b
    cls.a('par1', 'par2')
TypeError: unbound method a() must be called with Test instance as first argument
           (got str instance instead)
```

While in 3.2 it works just fine -- because unbound methods no longer exist, they are simply functions.

The reason `self` is not an instance is precisely because it is being called from a class method:  the class method does not get `self` so it cannot pass it along.

Comment: That's what I had started out thinking, but the claim is that the code works in 2.7, but fails in 3.2.

Comment: Perhaps, though, it is failing, but the TypeError is being caught somewhere else